# angular factory not passing data to controller

Tags: angularjs, mlab

I've got a simple factory passing data gathered from Mongolab into one controller, but I can't get it in another.

```
app.factory('User', function ($mongolabResourceHttp) {
    return $mongolabResourceHttp('users');
});
```

I've also got a Goal factory just like this. Both work fine as-is.

The above factory is working fine in my userCtrl, but I can't add it into my goalCtrl. I've got a userguid that I want to attach to goals. Basically: click link to user goals, create goals, userguid becomes part of saved goal.

```
app.controller('goalCtrl', function ($scope, $location, goals, users) {
    $scope.goals = goals;
    $scope.users = users;

    $scope.new = function () {
        $location.path('/');
    };

    ...

});
```

Any clues would be much appreciated. Thanks.

(I asked a similar question earlier today, but I think it had too many issues going on and it didn't get any responses. I have since worked out one of the issues and this question is to narrow it down further. So this isn't a complete repeat. Sorry if it bugs anyone though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject the service into your controller using the actual service name of 'User':

```
app.controller('goalCtrl', function ($scope, $location, goals, User) {
  $scope.users = User;
```

I'd also read up on angular service and dependency injection when you get a chance.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. So why does the injection of goals from the other factory and $scope.goals = goals; work?

Comment: did you initialize your goals factory as 'goals' or 'Goals'?

Comment: The factories and controllers were set up exactly the same, as the examples above. I've been using the controllers without any issues until I tried to include user in the goalCtrl. I thought I'd tried the uppercase User that Jeff mentioned, but I won't know for sure till I get to the office tomorrow.

Comment: Well, that didn't fix it. I must have something wrong somewhere else. But I'm giving the answer a check because I know it's answering my basic question and has nothing to do with what I must actually be screwing up. If anyone has a link to a tutorial or example of what I'm trying to do, I'd appreciate it.